# Iterate through ListView in custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a custom `ListView`. Each row contains a `TextView` and `ImageView`.

Look at screenshot:

[image]

On Item click I make that `ImageView` visible. But the problem is that only ONE `ImageView` should be visible at a time.

I think that the best approach is to set all other `ImageViews` as `INVISIBLE` on click. And after all images gone make a clicked one `VISIBLE`.

But I don't know how to iterate properly that in `Adapter`:

```
    private class TimeZoneItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Activity myContext;
    private ArrayList<String> datas;


    public TimeZoneItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        myContext = (Activity) context;
        datas = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = myContext.getLayoutInflater();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.postNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_item);
            viewHolder.postImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_mark);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.postNameView.setText(datas.get(position));

        viewHolder.postNameView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //clear all image views during iteration
                View view;
                for (int i = 0; i < datas.size(); i++) {
                    //dont know which parameter need there for proper iteration
                    view = getView(i, ?????, null);
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_mark);
                    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                if (viewHolder.postImageView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                    selectedTimeZone = viewHolder.postNameView.getText().toString();
                    viewHolder.postImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    viewHolder.postImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView postNameView;
        ImageView postImageView;
    }
}
```

Please help me or give some hints. I'm really confused with that already.

Comment: set tags for your rows and try to make imageview visible

Comment: I recommend you to create a custom object for your list with a String datas and a boolean selected. You instantiate selected to false by default and to true when you click on the imageview. When you do it, you also set all others objects selected paramater to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one solution:

```
private static View lastClicked = null;

... ...

viewHolder.postNameView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)parentRow.getTag();

            if(viewHolder.postImageView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) 
            {
                //clear last clicked image
                if(lastClicked != null)
                {
                   ViewHolder lastHolder = (ViewHolder)lastClicked.getTag();
                   lastHolder.postImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                selectedTimeZone = viewHolder.postNameView.getText().toString();
                viewHolder.postImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lastClicked = parentRow;
            } 
            else 
            {
                viewHolder.postImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                lastClicked = null;
            }

    });
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I like this approach, but there is an error at line: `ViewHolder lastHolder = (ViewHolder)lastClicked;`. Inconvertible types `View` and `ViewHolder`

Comment: Sorry I wrote it in hurry with mistake, now modified it. `getTag()` was missing

Comment: Oh..., you have accepted one answer? I suppose my solution is better

Comment: Can you give arguments why it is? He gave solution first so I marked it as correct. But if you prove that your approach is better I'll change the accepted answer. That would be fair I guess

Comment: `When clicking on an item, you should iterate the datas, *uncheck everything* and check the appropriate item.`, do you think that is good solution? In my solution just invisible last clicked image.

Comment: This will not work when you scroll the list around so that the Views are recycled.
When you scroll the list down the View objects that have just disappeared off the top are recycled and appear as new views at the bottom, so if the checked View scrolls off the top it could (not guaranteed!) be recycled and appear at the bottom and so show the wrong item as checked.
The View referenced by 'lastClicked' could be being used to render any of the list items, it will not 'stick' to the one you last clicked if it leaves the screen.
Views cannot be used to hold state because of this recycling.

Comment: My solution does not suggest you iterate the data and uncheck everything - it suggests you let Android redraw the views and when it does so it will consult your backing data to determine how to draw it.

Comment: @NeilS, wow, that's a reasonable argument. Unfortunately I can't submit both your answers. Both of them work fine. This one works faster for my particular problem since I don't have big listView. But your one is versatile for any case. I'd like to upvote both of you, guys, but my reputation is not bigh enough... Thanks for help! You did great

Comment: Try scrolling the checked item off the top or bottom of the list, this will not work - when the checked item is scrolled back into view it will no longer appear as checked. You may not have hundreds of items but what if a user has a small phone?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't store any information on the views. I believe that the listview recycles its views so thing could get messy. Try to separate the data from the views.

I would try a different approach. Your `datas` should be

```
ArrayList<MyData> datas;

public class MyData{
    String place;
    boolean: checked = false;
}
```

To populate the `datas` ArrayList you can do this

```
for (String s : objects){
    MyData d = new MyData();
    d.place = s;
}
```

Then in your adapters `getView` you should display/hide the imageView based on the value of `checked` like this:

```
private class TimeZoneItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyData> {
    private Activity myContext;
    private ArrayList<MyData> datas;


    public TimeZoneItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<MyDatas> datas) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, datas);
        this.datas = datas;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = myContext.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        }

        TextView postNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_item);
        TextView postImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_mark);

        postNameView.setText(this.datas.get(position).place);
        if(this.datas.get(position).checked){
            postImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            postImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

When clicking on an item, you should iterate the `datas`, uncheck everything and check the appropriate item. Then to update the listView you call

```
((TimeZoneItemAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and all the views will be updated automatically.

Comment: And how do I assign `ArrayList<MyData> datas;` to the parameter `ArrayList<String> objects`? Could you please write some more precise code?

Answer (score 1):

In the onClick you're iterating through the views and make sure that they all have the image hidden, and then after that setting the current one visible. You don't need to do that yourself, just tell the system to do it for you.

Note also that your current code will loop around all entries in the adapter and try and get a view for them... but not all of them will have one, the ones scrolled off the screen won't have a view.

The simplest way to do it is to remove everything from your onClick handler except the line where you set `selectedTimeZone`, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This will make Android redraw all of the currently-onscreen views.

Then below your `setText()` add:

```
if (datas.get(position).equals(selectedTimeZone)) {
   viewHolder.postImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else { 
   viewHolder.postImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

so when the system re-draws the views each view will be considered for having the image set to visible but only the current one will get it set.