# Get parent viewHolder in listView custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a problem. My listView contains items which are divided in 2 groups:

```
if (datas.get(position).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("after")) {
      viewHolder.postTimeView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_not_highlighted));
      viewHolder.postNameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_not_highlighted));
} else {
      viewHolder.postTimeView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
      viewHolder.postNameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}
```

It looks like:

[image]

the amount of "white" fields differs every time due to current time.

And **the problem is** I need to increase `textSize` and make `Bold` the **LAST** white field (see marked field).

How can I do that from custom adapter?

---

What I tried:

```
private int state = 0;
....
       if (datas.get(position).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("after")) {
            if (state == 0) {
                //Make parent placeholder Bold here
                parentHolder = (ViewHolder) parent.getTag();
                parentHolder.postNameView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                parentHolder.postTimeView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                parentHolder.postNameView.setTextSize(24);
                parentHolder.postTimeView.setTextSize(24);
                state++;
            }
            viewHolder.postTimeView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_not_highlighted));
            viewHolder.postNameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_not_highlighted));
        } else {
            viewHolder.postTimeView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            viewHolder.postNameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }
```

so state will be 0 only for once. But `parentHolder = (ViewHolder) parent.getTag();` doesn't work. It is `null`

Also I tried to find use of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186821/iterate-through-listview-in-custom-adapter/29187310?noredirect=1#comment46607790_29187310).

---

**EDIT:**
The amount of *White* and *Dirty white* items varies every time adapter is created since `.getStatus()` changes on server due to current time. It can be "before" (if starting time < current time) and "after" (current time < starting time).

And I need to **Mark** exactly that item, which is kind of "now" i.e. the first one "after".

The entire adapter (**UPDATED**):

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = myContext.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.channel_listview_item, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.postNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.channel_listview_item_name);
            viewHolder.postTimeView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.channel_listview_item_time);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (datas.get(position).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("before")) {

            viewHolder.postTimeView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            viewHolder.postNameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            viewHolder.postTimeView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_not_highlighted));
            viewHolder.postNameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_not_highlighted));

            //perform this 'if' only once at this position
             if (/*need such condition that occurs only for ONCE*/) {
                viewHolder.postNameView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                viewHolder.postTimeView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                viewHolder.postNameView.setTextSize(24);
                viewHolder.postTimeView.setTextSize(24);
                viewHolder.postTimeView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                viewHolder.postNameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        }
        viewHolder.postNameView.setText(datas.get(position).getTitle());
        viewHolder.postTimeView.setText(datas.get(position).getStart());
        return convertView;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView postTimeView;
    TextView postNameView;
}
```

Comment: Would value of state set to 0 based on the current time? That would make it more complicated. And I don't see the code for it. Meantime, I'll think about it. I like solving algorithms.

Comment: I don't see where setTag is used for the parent for getView(). However you can use viewHolder instead of the parent view instead. And you're setting the font size/style on both TextViews anyway.

Comment: @The Original Android, thanks for giving hints. But how and where should I set tag to parentHolder?

Comment: I don't know either. Can you just use viewHolder instead, like I said?

Comment: @The Original Android, yes. It actually works but not stable. Maybe you know how can I ensure that this `if (state == 0) {}` is entered **only** for once? I have few marked fields since adapter fills listview dynamically

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it since it is an algorithmic problem. The value of state has to depend and check on current time. Is that right?

Comment: Can you post your latest updated code?  You can add code under EDIT or UPDATE section to be clear.

Comment: @The Original Android, I appreciate your interest to this problem. Please check the latest **Edit**. There's only one **BUT**. I need to mark the first one "dirty white". Not the last one "white" like on picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have suggested code/design that I think should work eventually. It may be similar to your existing code design but I don't see code where **datas** list is setting the status for "before" or "after". Regardless I am using your terminology of "after" and try avoiding to change much code.

Suggested code:

```
int afterTimePosition = 0;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
   if (convertView == null) {
   ...
   } else {
      viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   if (position > afterTimePosition) {
      // Re-evaluate the AFTER line, MAY need to change it
      int currentTime = Server.getTime();     // replace getTime with a proper method call

      // Check time only after the AFTER line.

      // Need datas to save the date/time.
      if (datas.get(afterTimePosition).getTime() < currentTime) {
          // Need to change the AFTER line by evaluating time in the ArrayList against current time
          for (int i= afterTimePosition; i <= position; i++) {
              if (datas.get(i).getTime() >= currentTime) {
                  afterTimePosition = i;
                  break;      // found the new AFTER line
              }
          }
       }   // if datas...
    }

    if (afterTimePosition < position) {
        // BEFORE border line
        viewHolder.postTimeView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        viewHolder.postNameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    } else {
        // AFTER border line
        viewHolder.postTimeView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_not_highlighted));
        viewHolder.postNameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_not_highlighted));

        viewHolder.postNameView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        viewHolder.postTimeView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    }
```

Notes:

1. I am using the term AFTER meaning after the current time or the same.
2. My design idea is to save the row position into simple variable afterTimePosition. `afterTimePosition` is the **AFTER** line. It will be checked upon in code `if (afterTimePosition < position)` for determining when to highlight text. I try to be simple in design so that I won't get easily confused.
3. **ArrayList datas** need to save the time in integer or long. It takes only little amount of memory for it.
4. The code with `for (int i= afterTimePosition...` , signifies that the AFTER line or row items needs reevaluation. I think code is simple to understand.

Keep us posted...